# Is there a way to customize automatic spacing between in-line math equations?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

Is there a way that I can automatically fix the spacing between all the math characters for in line equations aside from using negative spaces? In the example, the spacing in "x \in U", "x \in A", and "x \in B" are large but I want it to be reduced to normal spacing aside from manually adding negative spaces.

My code is:

> For two sets $A$ and $B$, the \textbf{union} of $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A \cup B$, is the set of all $x \in U$ such that either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. This is expressed as:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5):

When there's a problem, typographic or otherwise, it's important to distinguish between **causes** and **symptoms** in order to have a chance to come up with satisfactory solutions.

What you've discovered is that by default, TeX allows considerable stretchiness in the whitespace that's inserted around operators with status `\mathrel`. (The default math status of `\in` is `mathrel`.) The basic amount of whitespace and the additional stretchiness are given by the parameter `\thickmuskip`; many (most?) LaTeX document classes define this length parameter as `5mu plus 5mu`, meaning that the minimum and maximum are given by 5mu and 10mu, respectively.

When I look at the screenshot you posted, the first thing I notice is *not* the (supposedly excessive) amount of whitespace around the three `\in` symbols in line 2. Rather, I notice that (a) *all* interword spaces in line 2 are considerably larger than those in line 1 and (b) the amount of whitespace after the period (aka full stop) at the sentence, toward the end of line 2, is also unusually large. The primary cause of this visual imbalance is quickly identified: It's the fact that the word "expressed" has only one valid hyphenation point. (TeX also has a thing about not wanting to create a hyphen on the penultimate line of a paragraph.)

What to do?

- Since the deep cause of the typographic problem is that there's no good way to hyphenate the word "expressed" where it's truly needed, one could try rewriting the start of the sentence, e.g., from "This is" to "This may be".
- Or, one could issue the instruction `\setlength{\thickmuskip}{5mu}` to delete the default stretch component.

In the following screenshot, the first enumerated item manages to replicate the screenshot you posted. The second item shows the result of modifying the start of the second sentence to "This may be" ... The third item shows what happens if the stretchability of `\thickmuskip` is cancelled.

[image]

Notice that the excessive spacing is gone in line 2 of item 3. However, it comes at the serious cost of TeX having to reduce the interword spacing in both lines 1 and 2, making for a very "compressed" look. In contrast, no such problem exists in item 2.

For me, modifying the value of `\thickmuskip` is the equivalent of treating a *symptom* of the problem. To treat the actual *cause*, it's worth trying to rewrite selected sentences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\textwidth{4in}
\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt]
\item 
For two sets $A$ and $B$, the \textbf{union} of $A$ and $B$, 
denoted by $A \cup B$, is the set of all $x \in U$ such that 
either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. This is expressed as 

\item 
For two sets $A$ and $B$, the \textbf{union} of $A$ and $B$, 
denoted by $A \cup B$, is the set of all $x \in U$ such that 
either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. This may be expressed as 

\setlength{\thickmuskip}{5mu}
\item 
For two sets $A$ and $B$, the \textbf{union} of $A$ and $B$, 
denoted by $A \cup B$, is the set of all $x \in U$ such that 
either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. This is expressed as 

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```